# Where should I set the frontend files in a Java project?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I developing a new site with a team. They sent to me a java project I must run on my local pc. The server starts on 8080 (And it must be in that port).

I have to create some front-end files (HTML/CSS/JS) and make ajax calls to services in that java project.

I guess I should not set my files on port 80, since I won't be able to perform ajax call cross ports..

Where should I set this html files inside the project?

**EDIT**
This is the web.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
        <display-name>SRA</display-name>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT**

This is the console logs

```
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Dec 05, 2015 11:31:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
^C^C^Cpablo@iridium:~/Documents/clients/test/SRA_backend/backend$ java -jar SRA.jar 
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Dec 05, 2015 12:01:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

**EDIT**
HTML PAGE

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java project structural best practices](http://dhruba.name/2008/10/13/java-project-structural-best-practices/)

```
 basic-maven-project/ 
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- src
 |   |-- main
 |   |   |-- java
 |   |   |-- resources
 |   |   `-- webapp

 |   |       `-- WEB-INF
     |   `-- test

|       |-- java

|       `-- resources
        `-- target
|-- classes
       `-- test-classes
```

Put your html files under your WEB-INF folder. I personally put my pages inside a webcontent folder directly under WEB-INF(Mainly because of access convenience and trying to mitigate some level of risks).

Comment: I added a index.html file in that folder, but it's not loading this file

Comment: @Pablo, did you add that index.html to your web.xml ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code of web.xml, I understand that with the welcome-message should be ok? or should I add another line?

Comment: @Pablo, The web.xml looks fine, Where are you deploying this(container like tomcat etc..)? Are you getting errors?

Comment: It's a tomcat. I think there is no error. I pasted the logs of the console

Comment: @Pablo, Load the page and test

Comment: I load `localhost:8080` but nothing else is logged

Comment: Neither nothing else logged

Comment: even when I load this page
`http://localhost:8080/SRA/authenticate` it returns a 405 error on the browser, (since it's a post). but nothing in the console

Comment: @Pablo, Post your index.html page

Comment: For now it just a very simple hello world page.. I posted in the description

Comment: @Pablo, how are you building your project?

Comment: `$ javac SRA.jar 
    error: Class names, 'SRA.jar', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error`

Comment: I have pasted my command in the last comment, I'm sending the `javac SRA.jar`  is it wrong? how should it be?

Comment: @Pablo, Its a web application, all you need to do is deploy it on tomcat. Are you using an ide?

Comment: No, I just need they told me just to run the command and start calling the services

Comment: @Pablo,  

    .jar files: The .jar files contain libraries, resources and accessories files like property files.

    .war files: The war file contains the web application that can be deployed on any servlet/jsp container. The .war file contains jsp, html, javascript and other files necessary for the development of web applications.

Comment: I need to make ajax calls to the services in that jar file. since the projects runs on port 8080, I need to set up the files inside the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97068/discussion-between-perdomoff-and-pablo).

Comment: @Pablo, What services? You posted an html hello world.

Comment: I must show a login page later, and then from there call to `http://localhost:8080/SRA/authenticate` authenticate.. but I try to show the hello world page (Where later I will make the login page), but nothing loads, I just get a 404

Comment: @Pablo What is SRA/authenticate?

Comment: Is the service in java, where I post username and password, and returns me the userID, to show him the next page

Comment: @Pablo, Web service not servlet?

Comment: I guess, they say REST services

Comment: @Pablo, and where is index.html?

Comment: inside the folder `src` (Inside the same folder as the jar), `src/main/webapp/index.html` also tried on `src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/index.html`

Comment: @Pablo, That's great! Good luck with your project.