# How to structure a java project?

Tags: java, url, intellij-idea, javafx

After two year of learning, I realize that my school didn't teach us any project structuring ...

I want to make games for a living, so I tried to start a little project on my own for self-learning. But I'm stuck on a little problem : I can't find the relative Path to my background's .gif file for my test-project.

Here 's how I've structured my project so far :
[image: project structure]

Is that a "proper" way to structure a project ? Even If this one is a small one, once I'll start a "real" big project, should I re-structure like that ?

For my path problem, here's some of the thing I've tried (I work with javaFx) :

```
Image bg = new Image("../assets/sprite/Backgrounds/farback.gif");
Image bg = new Image("/assets/sprite/Backgrounds/farback.gif");
Image bg = new Image("assets/sprite/Backgrounds/farback.gif");
Image bg = new Image("farback.gif");
Image bg = new Image("..\\assets\\sprite\\Backgrounds\\farback.gif");
Image bg = new Image("assets\\sprite\\Backgrounds\\farback.gif");
...
```

And so on, but none of them have work.
Also this is the first time I use a recursive URL on windows, so the problem may come from here ... I've look that up on google but didn't find anything useful ...

Comment: Check where your IDE places the executable and in which directory it executes it.

Comment: I highly recommend using Maven or Gradle and adopting [the standard project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: From looking at your screen shot ... it seems that so far all your java souce code is in the default package within one Main class. You might want to worry **more** about structuring your design / source code into packages / classes than worrying about resources (for now).

Comment: You claim you want to make games for a living.  Java definitely has some useful libraries for things like this (LWJGL/LibGDX/Slick2D), and there's nothing stopping you from making games in Java.  However, if you're getting deeper into game development, you might also want to consider other tools that are designed for that task.  Unity/UE4 are pretty much the standards in the field, and GameMaker is a useful prototyping tool (not that you can't make full games with it either...).

Comment: You should check out the [jMonkeyEngine](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine) game engine. It's written in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Maven has become a standard for most open source projects.  I'd recommend that you follow their directory structure and naming standards.

The other standard you need to be aware of is web app packaging in WARs.  You'll see a /web folder with that represents the root of your WAR context, with a /WEB-INF child.  You usually put your web asserts at the root of the WAR context.

The Maven convention will have you put your web stuff under /main/resources/static.  When you have it build your WAR file it'll put them in the right spot.

Another great recommendation would be [Spring Boot](http://spring.io).  It might be a little advanced for you, but they also have good recommendations about how to structure applications.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. But Maven seems a little to complex for what I try to do for now ... But maybe I'm wrong ^^"

Comment: Any recommendations for a good Maven tutorial for beginner ? I'm currently reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/index.htm) but I'd like to have different view on the subject ^^

Comment: If you're a beginner anything will do.  Look at the Maven materials.

Comment: I sympathize about Maven.  I found it daunting at first, too.  My point is that you can use the directory structure without using Maven, but you're prepared that way for the day when you do decide to take the plunge.

Comment: ok thks ! I started a new project with Maven, and my Image bg = new Image("img/sprite/background/farback.gif"); works ^^ I don't really know how to properly use Maven but it seem that just starting a Maven project and using the Maven's Standard Directory Layout are enough for now ... ^^

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link, the author goes into more detail on structuring:
 [Java project structural best practices](http://dhruba.name/2008/10/13/java-project-structural-best-practices/)

```
 basic-maven-project/ 
 |-- pom.xml
 |-- src
 |   |-- main
 |   |   |-- java
 |   |   |-- resources
 |   |       `-- webapp

 |   |       `-- WEB-INF
 |        `-- test

 |       |-- java

 |       `-- resources
        `-- target
 |-- classes
       `-- test-classes
```

See chosen answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106492/where-should-i-set-the-frontend-files-in-a-java-project/34106844#34106844)